# Using function recursively causes increase in model size in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use a function to calculate mean squared error in in within `tf.Session()` at every epoch. However, if I save the model at every step, the size of the saved files increases with step size.

When I use the function `get_mse()`, the size of `check_points` saved after every epoch increases. However, when I use a simple statement to calculate `mse` i.e. `MSE`, it does not happen so. What I am doing wrong?

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.losses.losses_impl import Reduction, compute_weighted_loss
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

def get_mse(
    labels, predictions, weights=1.0, name="mse", scope=None,
    loss_collection=ops.GraphKeys.LOSSES,
    reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS):
  with ops.name_scope(scope, name,
                      (predictions, labels, weights)) as scope:
    predictions = math_ops.to_float(predictions)
    labels = math_ops.to_float(labels)
    predictions.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
    losses = math_ops.squared_difference(predictions, labels)
    return compute_weighted_loss(
losses, weights, scope, loss_collection, reduction=reduction)

true  = np.random.random((100,1))
pred = np.random.random((100,1))

variable_to_save = tf.Variable(true)
true_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 1], name='labels')
pred_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 1], name='predictions')

MSE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred_ph - true_ph), name='get_mse')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=100)
    for epoch in range(10):
        mse = sess.run(get_mse(true_ph, pred_ph), feed_dict={'labels:0': true, 'predictions:0':pred})   #this increases size of checkpoints after each epoch
        #mse = sess.run(MSE, feed_dict={'labels:0': true, 'predictions:0': pred})   #running this does not increases size of check_points
        saver.save(sess, os.getcwd(), global_step=epoch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call get_mse() you build yet another bunch of computation graph nodes. I.e. every time you create yet another version of `predictions`, `labels`, and `losses`.

Call get_mse() once and store the result into a variable, say `mse_computer`. Then use `sess.run(mse_computer, feed_dict=....` instead.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code should rather be as following:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.losses.losses_impl import Reduction, compute_weighted_loss
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

def get_mse(
    labels, predictions, weights=1.0, name="mse", scope=None,
    loss_collection=ops.GraphKeys.LOSSES,
    reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS):
    with ops.name_scope(scope, name,
                      (predictions, labels, weights)) as scope:
        predictions.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
        losses = math_ops.squared_difference(predictions, labels)
    return compute_weighted_loss(
        losses, weights, scope, loss_collection, reduction=reduction)

true  = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
pred = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
true_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='labels')
pred_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='predictions')
mse_tensor = get_mse(true_ph, pred_ph)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=100)
    for epoch in range(10):
        mse_val = sess.run(mse_tensor, feed_dict={true_ph: true, pred_ph:pred})   #this increases size of checkpoints after each epoch
        saver.save(sess, os.getcwd(), global_step=epoch)
```

In your case at each iteration you add additional operations and tensors to graph and hence, its size grows.